# CouchDB view - reduce / group duplicate key values to array

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I've got a view on my couch db, which outputs  data in this format:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["Partner1","Voucher Type 1"],"value":true},
{"key":["Partner1","Voucher Type 2"],"value":true},
{"key":["Partner2","Voucher Type 1"],"value":true},
{"key":["Partner3","Voucher Type 1"],"value":true},
{"key":["Partner4","Voucher Type 1"],"value":true}
]}
```

What I'm trying to get do is effectively 'group' the Partner | Voucher Type,
So in the example above, It would return be something like:

```
Partner1: ["Voucher Type 1", "Voucher Type 2"]
Partner2: ["Voucher Type 1"]
Partner3: ["Voucher Type 1"]
Partner4: ["Voucher Type 1"]
```

Currently, my map reduce functions look like this:

Map:

```
function(
    emit([doc.PartnerName, doc.VoucherType], 1);
}
```

Reduce:

```
function(keys, values) {
    return true;
}
```

I'm querying with `group=true`

I suspect I need to do more in the reduce function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using the following reduce:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce){
  var item = {};
  r=[];

  values.forEach(function(value){
    item[value] = value;
  });

  for(var i in item){
    r.push(item[i]);
  }

  return r; 
}
```

Comments welcome if this is incorrect, but it's returning me the data in the desired form:

```
PartnerName: VoucherType[]
```

Comment: The parameter `values` appears twice in the function signature which is probably not intended. It was not clear to me that you want to have unique values, which is likely what you want to achieve by turning the `values` array into the `item` object. Anyway, I guess you will have to consider the rereduce case separately as you will end up with array keys in the `items` object otherwise.

Comment: change `r = r.push(item[i]);` for `r = r.concat(i);` if you want better visualization of your data

Answer (score 2):

Your aim is not to reduce the amount of data, only to change the format.
So do not use a reduce function, use a [list function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#list-functions).

```js
function(head, req) {
    var lastKey, row, dedup;

    while (row = getRow()) {
        if (row.key !== lastKey) {
            dedup = {};
            send('\n' + row.key + ': ');
        }

        if (!dedup[row.value]) {
            if (row.key === lastKey) {
                send(', ');
            }

            dedup[row.value] = true;
            send(row.value);
        }

        lastKey = row.key;
    }
}
```

This one just gives you a plaintext listing, but you can add whatever formatting you desire, e.g. JSON.

```
Partner1: Voucher Type 1, Voucher Type 2
Partner2: Voucher Type 1
```

If you don't need the de-duplication, then it's even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following design document:

```js
{
   "_id": "_design/ddoc",
   "views": {
       "partners": {
           "map": function(doc) {
                      emit(doc.PartnerName, doc.VoucherType);
                  },
           "reduce": function(keys, values) {
                         var voucherTypes = [];
                         values.forEach(function(v) {
                             voucherTypes = voucherTypes.concat(v);
                         });
                         return voucherTypes;
                     }
       }
   }
}
```

What you could do is to make use of the reduce function with the `group=true` parameter, i.e.

```
<couchdb>/<database>/_design/ddoc/_view/partners?group=true
```

which would give you something like this:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"Partner1","value":["Voucher Type 2","Voucher Type 1"]},
{"key":"Partner2","value":["Voucher Type 1"]},
{"key":"Partner3","value":["Voucher Type 2"]}
]}
```

However, this is rather discouraged because you are building up data structures in a reduce function. Reduce functions should return simple, usually numeric values. Also, the above reduce function might break in a rereduce case. I have not tested this. As an alternative I can propose to realize the query only with the map function, that is

```
<couchdb>/<database>/_design/ddoc/_view/partners?reduce=false&key="Partner1"
```

which would return:

```
{"total_rows":4,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"97c7ee4d90f57407bb1f4f680d20967b","key":"Partner1","value":"Voucher Type 1"},
{"id":"97c7ee4d90f57407bb1f4f680d20a049","key":"Partner1","value":"Voucher Type 2"}
]}
```

Comment: Trouble is, there could be a million documents, so it would output one million rows. I'm trying to get (basically) Name : VoucherType[] (like the first idea with group=true)

Comment: With the first option, I'm getting "Reduce output must shrink more rapidly"

Comment: Ah, I was afraid that this is going to happen. Basically this tells you that the reduce function I have shown in my answer is a bad idea. You *can* change the field `reduce_limit` in the configuration to `false`, but I think you better *should not*. See also: http://grokbase.com/t/couchdb/user/12cb1kk47v/what-is-the-purpose-of-reduce-limit-setting

Comment: In this case you definitely should not, as the size of the data isn't reducing at all. Running the map-reduce is going to be very inefficient.